# What is the purpose of square brackets after a variable

Tags: javascript

I'm debugging code that someone else wrote and can not figure out what they had in mind.

At the end of method there is a return statement shown below

```
return params[name] || null;
```

If params is an object (it is in this case) then 
params.name
or
params['name'] would return the value of that function(method)

Two things are a mystery. In the docboc, the author stated that it this method would return a string. Clearly, it does not.

Secondly, since it is returning an object, how would I properly reference that value?
(Note: I do NOT know what the key is before hand)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Its how you access properties of an object by name, or at least, whatever the value of "name" is.

Comment: `params[name]` can be a string

Comment: put `console.log(params);` before your return to see the data

Comment: When I run the code as shown, I get a response "undefined". 
Which I would expect, because "name" is not a key.

Answer (score 2):

Square brackets in JavaScript allow you to access Objects and Arrays by index. For an example this would be a base 0 integer for Arrays, e.g. `someArray[0]`. For objects this would be the key, e.g. `someObject[‘key’]`.

Comment: That's right... but in the code, the "index" was referenced as "name". How is that supposed to work?

Comment: “name” is an argument passed to the function.

Comment: For example, `getUrlParameter(“test”, “http://example.com/test)`, “test” would be the index.

Comment: Exactly. Almost exactly.. here it is http://example.com?something=xyz

Answer (score 1):

Your statement return params[name] || null is looking for params (array / obj) and name (index / key) 
So if your params for example is an object and name is the variable for the keys.
and you need to get its value, you would do params[name] . since name is not under quotations I am assuming its a var defined somewhere

Answer (score 0):

Square Brackets (`[]`) allows you to access properties of any object or element of an array at a specific index 
for example :

```
const obj = {a:true};
```

then `obj['a']` will return true;

Or `const arr = ['hello','world'];`

then `arr[0]` will return `'hello'`;